# Invalid object name 'dbo.SS_MAP_EntityWidgetMapping' in nopcommerce

Tags: sql-server-2008, nopcommerce

I have deployed **NopCommerce-3.5** in **Godaddy** Hosting and it works perfectly. But when I installed and Enabled SevenSpike plugins then system shows me

> Invalid object name `dbo.SS_MAP_EntityWidgetMapping` error

I looked in my database tables but there is no table with this name.

In [this](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/11224/invalid-object-name-dbonop_customerrole-error-in-many-tasks.aspx#45835) post, he says to create table manually but where may I get the table definition of `dbo.SS_MAP_EntityWidgetMapping`

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: see mostly when you install plugin on that time that plugin create it's table in db, i think there might some issue in you plugin installation try to uninstall it and then again install it may be your issue solve...

Comment: I saw that another plugin was not installed correctly. I uninstalled that plugin and works fine. Thanks.